# Rails remote link update record that also opens the link

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, onclick

My app contains a citation model, which belongs to a client model. Each citation is simply local business listing that the client has on some third party directory, say yellowpages.com for instance.

So on my client show view I have all the listings that belong to that client, and you can click a "view listing" link that opens the url for that listing like so:

```
<%= @citations.each do |c| %>
  <%= link_to "View Listing", c.listing_url, target: '_blank' %>
<% end %>
```

When the link is clicked, I want to use ajax to call a method in the controller that updates the "updated_at" column for that record, on top of opening the link. Can I do this using the build in remote method? Or will I have to write my own javascript event listener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the exact behavior you are asking for I would suggest writing your own javascript event listener.  But, here is an alternative approach that has nearly the same effect.  It uses ajax links to hit your controller, but the new browser tab won't open until after your Rails app responds.

Change your links to something like this:

```
<%= @citations.each do |c| %>
  <%= link_to "View Listing", {:controller => :citations, :action => :my_action, :citation_id => c.id}, :remote => :true %>
<% end %>
```

In your controller, load the citation and do a touch:

```
class CitationsController < ApplicationController
  def my_action
    @citation = Citation.find( params.require(:citation_id) )
    @citation.touch # updates the updated_at column
  end
end
```

In the response view, `my_action.js.erb`, open the listing_url in a new browser tab/window:

```
// same effect as a link with target = _blank
window.open("<%= j @citation.listing_url %>");
```

Comment: This all makes sense, except I'm running into an issue with the routing. Here's what my nested routes for citations look like now `resources :clients do
    resources :citations do
      collection do
        post :import
      end
    end
  end` how should i add the route for the new action?

Comment: There a multiple ways to define your application routes and I think resource routing is a bit confusing for novice Rails developers.  A simple way to define a single route for the example answer I gave is to add this to your `config/routes.rb` file: `get 'citation_listing', to: 'citations#my_action'`